# Sine Function with an exponential amplitude with a plusminus in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, plot

I want to graph this expression:

[image]

But i dont understand how to manage time and plusminus in the code.

I need to get something like this (this image is a voltage graph in Simulink/Matlab)

[image]

Comment: Start by trying to get the left half. The rest is just the same curve mirrored, shifted in time and offset vertically to match the first half's last y-value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to define a `t` array with time values:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 0.01, N)
```

then you can compute `Vr` as a function of time. The expression you reported contains a ± so it is not a mathematical function: you have to define two different functions (arrays) one for each sign:

```
Vr_plus = 15000*np.exp(-2500*t)*np.sin(t)
Vr_minus = -15000*np.exp(-2500*t)*np.sin(t)
```

Finally, you can draw the plot:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(t, Vr_plus)
ax.plot(t, Vr_minus)

plt.show()
```

### Complete code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 0.01, N)

Vr_plus = 15000*np.exp(-2500*t)*np.sin(t)
Vr_minus = -15000*np.exp(-2500*t)*np.sin(t)


plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(t, Vr_plus)
ax.plot(t, Vr_minus)

plt.show()
```

[image]